# what is the explanation of output of C# statement

Tags: c#

> Can you explain the following methods:

```
public static bool bool1(string v1)
{
  return bool1(v1, "Y");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't even compiles or there's something missing.

Comment: this a method overload you have another implementation of this method somewhere

Comment: The overload you are referring to isn't in the post.

Comment: You asked us to explain the following methods, but there is only one method.

Comment: Please see this link: https://www.dotnetperls.com/overload

Comment: That is, where is the definition of `bool1(string x, string y){...}`

Comment: That method calls another method bool1() with different signature, stores the result in a temporary invisible variable and then returns the result of that temporary variable

Comment: What is that temporary invisible variable?

Answer (score 1):

The outermost method "bool1" takes a string and returns a boolean value (true or false).

To determine whether to return true or false, it calls another method with the same name, but that method takes two string values. Having multiple methods with the same name but taking different arguments is called "overloading" a method, and the second method is called a method overload.

Since you have not included the definition of the overload taking two strings, it's not possible to say what that one does internally, only that it takes two strings and returns a boolean value.

Comment: The other method is

Comment: public static bool bool1(string v1, string trueval)

Comment: { return v1?.ToUpper() == trueval?.ToUpper();}